# Want to debug Pintos with Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, operating-system, pintos

Pintos:
http://courses.mpi-sws.org/os-ss11/assignments/pintos/pintos_11.html

Goal: properly execute the instructions in the link under "F2: Eclipse". They don't work for spit. I can communicate between 2 terminals via "target remote localhost:1234", but apparently not between a terminal and Eclipse (without GNU debugging server).

Alternatively, if it's not possible to be the host and target machine simultaneously without GDBserver, say that as well so I can stop going in circles.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: sounds like a fun class

Comment: Better when its free :)

Comment: Its a free class? Thats cool

Comment: Well, the material, like damn near everything else, is free on the internet. Anyway, we are going in circles. I'm going to edit the question to something more palatable.

Comment: 1.2mm people reached, top 2% of users, nothing else to add?

Comment: Sorry Gustav, I have not dabbled with this, so i cant give you any insight from the top of my head =/

Comment: Thanks anyway. I have someone working on it as we speak, but that only came about as of today. Unfortunately the documentation provided is just crap and needs to be updated.